# Deleting Electrum wallet and setting up new one

Tags: electrum, synchronization, signature

I set up an Electrum wallet before I learnt that you should verify the signature. While I went straight to the electrum.org website to download it, I would still like to be secure, just in case. So I want to start again (I had no crypto yet in this wallet).

What should I do to be sure that I have eliminated all the files for the old wallet from my PC (Windows 10), so there is no chance of confusion when I download a second time? I downloaded the Windows Installer version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Electrum on Windows, in my opinion just checking that it is signed with the correct code-signing certificate is sufficient; if any security beyond that is desired, you should use a hardware wallet with Electrum. When you open it, if the Windows UAC prompt says the file is "from the verified publisher Electrum Technologies GmbH", then that should be assurance that the file is the correct Electrum installer.

However, if you just want to delete the wallet files from the old Electrum installation, they are typically located in `%appdata%/Electrum`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as eliminating the wallet files; just navigate to the directory used by electrum to save/open wallet files and delete "wallet_1", "wallet_2", etc.. or whatever custom named file you may have chosen for your wallet. Getting rid of the actual software is fairly straightforward also; <strike>if you downloaded the standalone executable file then just delete that. If you downloaded the setup files and installed from there then</strike> either use the Uninstall.exe from the installation directory or go to the Programs and Features section in the Control Panel, select Electrum, and click Uninstall.